# Finding integral of $\int (x\sqrt{2ax-x^2}) dx$ where a is a positive constant

Tags: calculus

As in the title.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\int x \sqrt{2ax-x^2} dx=\int x\sqrt {2ax-x^2-a^2+a^2} dx=\int x\sqrt {a^2-(x-a)^2}dx$

Let $t=x-a$, the answer will be clear.